# Proof by induction of sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is from Apostol's Vol. 1 One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

*Page 40. Exercise 10.* Prove by induction, that for $n\ge1$ we have $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{m=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}.$$ *The attempt at a solution*: To prove by induction, I understand that the first step is to show that statement is true for base case, in this case, since $n\ge1$, we have $\frac{1}{2}=1$ since $\frac{(-1)^{1+1}}{1}=1$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $n=1$, 
$$\sum_{m=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}=\sum_{m=1}^{\color{red}{2}}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}=\frac{(-1)^{1+1}}{1}+\frac{(-1)^{2+1}}{2}=\frac 12.$$

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try to prove again, now that I understand what's going on :D.

Comment: @GeorgeDirac: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The second sum has two summands.